# Indian Income Tax System Rebate on Education Loan and House Rent

Tags: india, loans, tax-deduction, education, deduction

I am a recent graduate and will be starting my job in a couple of days.

My offer Letter says

> CTC Offered:
>
> ● X LPA (can't disclose the actual amount) ->  fixed

and it is written that:

> Applicable Income Tax (TDS) will be deducted from your monthly taxable earnings.

So my question is that I have completed my graduation, so I will be paying the EMIs so can I get a rebate on Education Loan from Tax and I also live on rent with my family so can I also get a rebate on that as well?

Also, I am new on this platform, so I am sorry if I missed something.

Comment: Welcome new user!  Seems like a fine question.  What is "LPA" ?!

Comment: Lakhs Per Annum

Comment: Yes, you will get tax exemption on [education loan under section 80E](https://cleartax.in/s/section-80e-deduction-interest-education-loan) and [House Rent Allowance under section 80GG](https://www.policybazaar.com/income-tax/save-income-tax-on-house-rent-allowance/). For these, you need to inform your employer about these expenses to avoid TDS. Or you can claim these back when filling Income Tax Return.

Comment: Can you edit and make the questions precise. You can get rebate... but you are also asking prepayment is better or not.... this needs exact numbers to answer

Comment: Sure, Let me remove the prepayment part, will create a separate question for that later since comments told me that I will get a rebate.

Comment: @Fattie In India there is a convention for numbers where 100 k is a 1 lakh and 10 million is 1 crore.

Comment: @CanuteS - believe or not I actually lived there for some years!!!

Answer (score 0):

The technical term for it is a "deduction from taxable income" you have to disclose the EMI and rent with proper proofs to you employer and once they enter this into their payroll processing system your TDS amount deducted will reduce to the extent of the deduction allowable under the tax laws applicable for the year.

Most employers have a online system which lets you enter these values when joining and at the beginning of each year so that by the end of the year your TDS deducted is exactly equal to your total income tax due by the end of the financial year.